# Does Arquillian @Deployment has a URL path?

Tags: unit-testing, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

With @Deployment on Arquillian framework you can deploy a WebArchive file on your container. I want to send HTTP Requests to this container. Does this container have a specific URL? Can I set it to have a specific URL?

I have read about @ArquillianResource, but on the code down below it always returns null.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @ArquillianResource
    private URL baseURL2;

    @ArquillianResource(MyClass.class)
    private URL baseServerURL;

    @Deployment 
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() { 
        WebArchive w = ShrinkWrap 
                .create(WebArchive.class)
                .addPackages(true, "my.package")
                .addClass(MyClass.class);
        System.out.println(w);
        return w;
    }

    @Test @RunAsClient  
    public void firstTest(@ArquillianResource(MyClass.class) URL baseURL) {
        System.out.println(baseURL);
        System.out.println(baseURL2);
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
    }
```

output:

```
null
null
```

Any help given is appreciated.

Comment: Can you try to set @Deployment(testable=false) ?

Comment: The argument for `@ ArquillianResource` is expected to be a class that implements `javax.servlet.Servlet`. Is this the case? In any event, this argument will only select the correct application context based upon the discovery of this servlet, not the URL to the servlet itself.

Comment: No, I am not using a Servlet. My project is not using Servlets, it is using a jaxrs Application. Is there a way I can still use @ArquillainResource ??
I have tried testable=false testable=true, nothing happens.

I am using a javax.ws.rs.core.Application and JAX-RS resources.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set all this:

```
String port = System.getProperty("server.port");
if (port == null) {
    RestAssured.port = Integer.valueOf(8080);
} else {
    RestAssured.port = Integer.valueOf(port);
}

String basePath = System.getProperty("server.base");
if (basePath == null) {
    basePath = "/basePath/rest/";
}
RestAssured.basePath = basePath;

String baseHost = System.getProperty("server.host");
if (baseHost == null) {
    baseHost = "http://localhost";
}
RestAssured.baseURI = baseHost;

RestAssured.defaultParser = Parser.JSON;
```

A better approach is to add this code to a parent class and all or your tests to extend this functionality.

So with the above configuration if you have a url like http://localhost:8080/persons/{id}/roles you can call a rest from your test like this:

```
List<SecurityRole> personGet = Arrays.asList(given().header("Accept-Language", "en").header("Authorization", getToken()).pathParam("id", person.getId()).when().get("/persons/{id}/roles")
.then().statusCode(200).extract().response().as(SecurityRole[].class));
```

You do not have to worry about the urls just your end point url.

Comment: This is all completely unnecessary when using Arquillian